# Shouldn't populist badge be given if the accepted question has negative score?

Tags: bug, badges

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28984789/3995261) the accepted answer has score of n = -5 and another answer has m = +14, 19 more than the accepted one. Still, the populist badge was not given to the author of the second answer. The badge's description reads:

> Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x

so... I'm not sure how the check is done but at least m > n + 10 and m > n*2. Even m > 2|n|. Why the badge was not given to jaffa? Is this a bug?

I believe the correct check should be `m > n + 10 && m > max(n*2,0)`.

Comment: Outscoring a downvoted answer is too simple to do, it must be an answer that users find acceptable.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42868/144883

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x

is a densely packed sentence which means two things:

1. Accepted answer has score > 10
2. Your answer has score > 2*(accepted answer score).

Condition 1 fails here. More details at [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for#68258)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Is wording "Highest scoring answer that outscored by more than 2x an accepted answer with score of more than 10" correct in terms of English grammar? I think it would be easier to understand that way.